# Are elements of a 'const std::vector<std::string>' immutable as well? (in C++11)

Tags: c++11, vector

This will compile:

```
std::vector<std::string> test{"hello"};
std::cout << test[0] << '\n';
test[0].append(" world");
std::cout << test[0] << '\n';
```

Output:

```
hello
hello world
```

This will not:

```
const std::vector<std::string> test{"hello"};
std::cout << test[0] << '\n';
test[0].append(" world");
std::cout << test[0] << '\n';
```

More importantly, as expected, this will not compile:

```
std::vector<const std::string> test{"hello"};
std::cout << test[0] << '\n';
test[0].append(" world");
std::cout << test[0] << '\n';
```

but sadly, neither will this:

```
std::vector<const std::string> test{"hello"};
std::cout << test[0] << '\n';
```

There are many differing answers to questions about immutability of std::vector and details on cppreference.com (Assignable, CopyAssignable...). But getting down to what I'd like to be able to do (so the question is: "how do I do *this*..."?) --

1. define a std::vector<std::string> that will allow me to ensure the elements, once added, cannot be changed -- but the vector can be changed, including adding new and deleting existing elements and changing their order (std::vector<const std::string> failed though seemed a reasonable approach without understanding the details of std::vector)
2. define a std::vector<std::string> that will not allow me to change the vector or its elements (const std::vector<std::string> seems to work)
3. define a std::vector<std::string> that allows the existing elements to be modified but the vector itself will always have the same number and order of elements (this is not particularly interesting to me)
4. std::vector<std::string> is fully modifiable.

Comment: Please fix your examples. None of them will compile because of obvious syntax mistakes and probably naming mistakes.

Comment: Why do you want #1? Removing an element and adding another in its place is indistinguishable from modifying the existing element in place. What actual problem are you trying to solve, that you believe an answer to this question would help you get closer to a solution?

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik I'm trying to reduce the chances of coding errors by making it hard to do the wrong thing. Adding elements to the vector must be allowed, but once a string is added, it should never be changed. I'd rather disallow deleting elements but this is a compromise. Also, it seemed a good opportunity to better understand how std::vector works - and I listed all four permutations as my thinking about how I'd expect it to work would be similar to the [const char const *] paradigm -- but apparently it is not.

Comment: This requirement looks a bit weird: you can't change `test[0]` directly, but you can copy it, remove it, alter the copy, and add it back, so you still have a different `test[0]` after the copy-remove-alter-restore. Now the requirement might be perfectly valid in some case I cannot yet imagine, but I think it's definitely strange enough that there is no easy way with standard containers.

Comment: @Jack Deeth fixed.

Comment: @MSalters as above, the idea is to make it hard(er) to do the wrong thing. Copying, deleting original, modifying copy and adding back is a lot more that has to be done wrong then simply modifying the original in place. Perhaps the answer is that a const std::vector should be considered const as a monolithic object, including all contained elements. That was not what I expected, which is that a non-POD element was like a pointer, and as long as the "pointer" didn't change, the vector could be const but the referenced element could.